# Defining a custom expression containing a conditional

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to define an expression for computing the `sum` of a `polars.DataFrame` column. The desired `sum` operation has the property that it's the usual `polars` `sum` operation, except in the case that there are only `null` elements in the column. In that case I want the sum to be `null` also.

This can be achieved using a conditional, e.g.

```py
frame = pl.from_dict({
    "A": [None, None, None], 
    "B": [0.0, None, None]})
result = frame.select([
    pl.when(pl.col(col).is_not_null().sum() > 0)
      .then(pl.col(col).sum())
      .otherwise(None)
          for col in frame.columns
          ])
print(result)
>>> shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f32 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ null┆ 0.0 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

The conditional expression is very long, ideally I'd like to be able to define (a function?) `mysum` such that I can get the same writing

```py
result = frame.select(pl.all()).mysum()
```

OR

```py
result = frame.select(pl.all()).map(mysum)
```

or similar. I simply would like to hide (encapsulate) the conditional statement, possibly passing a `min_count` argument (like in pandas.DataFrame.sum) so that I can use it from within in the `select` `with_columns` and `groupby` contexts.

Unfortunately I am just getting started with polars and I am not sure what's the best/canonical way to achieve this.

I am also struggling to understand the difference between the following four statements (which all compute the column wise sum). I have indicated my best-guess/preliminary understanding as inline comments, but would be very glad if this could be unraveled for me.

```py
# i) Method call on `polars.DataFrame`
frame.sum()
# ii) Select context with list of expressions? each computing the sum of a single column
frame.select([pl.col("A").sum(), pl.col("B").sum()])
# iii) Select context with a list of two `pl.col` expressions?, method call on the resulting `polars.DataFrame`?
frame.select([pl.col("A"), pl.col("B")]).sum()
# iv) Select context with a `pl.col` expression? applied to a list of columns chained with a (single?) sum expression?
frame.select(pl.col(["A", "B"]).sum())
```

Finally I'd like to understand whether my 'custom' sum (expression?) can be used with any/all of the four above statements.

### Solution

Thanks to all the very helpful explanations, I ended up defining a custom expression which I applied using the `polars.Expr.pipe` method, cf. below

```py
def nullsum(expr: pl.Expr, min_count: int = 0) -> pl.Expr:
    if min_count > 0:
        return pl.when(expr.is_not_null().sum() >= pl.lit(min_count)).then(expr.sum())
    else:
        return expr.sum()

result = frame.select(pl.col("A", "B").pipe(nullsum, min_count=1))
print(result)
>>> shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f32 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ null┆ 0.0 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's not a duplicate of the question you linked.

Answer (score 1):

**How to achieve the ability to do `result = frame.select(pl.all()).mysum()`**

The good thing here is that you can do even better than that because:

1. `.select(pl.all())` is completely redundant.
2. `.otherwise(None)` is also redundant.

Let's take what you wrote (with some little tweaks) and put it in a function:

```
def mysum(frame):
    return (
        frame
        .select(pl.when(pl.col(col).is_not_null().any())
                .then(pl.col(col).sum())
                for col in frame.columns)
)
```

Now you can do `mysum(frame)` which is close to what you wanted. To get it so that you can do `frame.mysum()` you need to assign your function into the `pl.DataFrame` namespace like this

```
pl.DataFrame.mysum=mysum
```

With that you can now do

```
frame.mysum()
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ B   │
│ ---  ┆ --- │
│ f32  ┆ f64 │
╞══════╪═════╡
│ null ┆ 0.0 │
└──────┴─────┘
```

**To get min_count feature**

```
def mysum(frame, min_count=1):
    return (
        frame
        .select(pl.when(pl.col(x).is_not_null().sum()>=pl.lit(min_count))
                   .then(pl.col(x).sum())
                   for x in frame.columns)
)
pl.DataFrame.mysum=mysum
```

We gave min_count a default value of 1 so you can still do `frame.mysum()` but you can also do `frame.mysum(2)` (or however many you want the min_count to be).

Don't be confused by the fact that the function used the name `frame` to think it only works with *this* frame. It will work on any frame until you restart the kernel and need to reload the custom function. For instance you can do:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,3,None, None, 10],
    'b': [1,2,3,4, None, 10],
    'c': [None,2,None,None, None, 10]
})
df.mysum()
shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 16  ┆ 20  ┆ 12  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
df.mysum(5)
shape: (1, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ 20  ┆ null │
└──────┴─────┴──────┘
```

and so on.

**Distinguishing between your cases**

```
# i) Method call on `polars.DataFrame`
frame.sum()
# ii) Select context with list of expressions? each computing the sum of a single column
frame.select([pl.col("A").sum(), pl.col("B").sum()])
# iii) Select context with a list of two `pl.col` expressions?, method call on the resulting `polars.DataFrame`?
frame.select([pl.col("A"), pl.col("B")]).sum()
# iv) Select context with a `pl.col` expression? applied to a list of columns chained with a (single?) sum expression?
frame.select(pl.col(["A", "B"]).sum())
```

From here, i and iii are essentially the same. In iii when you do `frame.select([pl.col("A"), pl.col("B")])`, the `.select([pl.col("A"), pl.col("B")])` is redundant because the frame only has those two columns and you're not doing anything with them except returning them. In both cases you're dispatching the `DataFrame.sum()` method.

ii and iv are also both the same. Polars is flexible in how you dispatch methods to expressions. When you want to do the same operation to multiple columns then you can do, as in what you've done in iv, `pl.col('A','B').sum()`. Other than, perhaps readability, there's no benefit to doing `pl.col("A").sum(), pl.col("B").sum()`. Another thing is that polars uses *args and **kwargs almost everywhere so you rarely need to explicitly use lists so instead of

```
frame.select([pl.col("A").sum(), pl.col("B").sum()])
```

you can just write

```
frame.select(pl.col("A").sum(), pl.col("B").sum())
```

Same for

```
frame.select(pl.col(["A", "B"]).sum())
```

it can just be written as

```
frame.select(pl.col("A", "B").sum())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive explanations. This helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive explanations. This helps a lot. I understand that I need to add (hotpatch) `mysum` to the `polars.DataFrame` class in order to be able to use it as a method call on the `DataFrame` object. So I have understood that I can either have `Expr.sum` or `DataFrame.sum`. What if I would want to have `Expr.mysum` so that I can e.g. do frame.select(pol.col("A").mysum(min_count=2)), i.e. I'd like to be able to define a "custom expression" that I can use in a chained statement rather than a new `DataFrame` level method.

Comment: @BenjaminTrendelkamp-Schroer It's basically the same. You make a function whose return is what's in the inside of this one's `select` and then you put that in `pl.Expr.mysum`